# How to fix c# multilingual application, so that it can work once installed and not only in VS2018 environment

Tags: c#, installation, multilingual, resourcemanager

I am developing a multilingual application using ResourceManager and custom resource files. The application does not have to use the current PC culture, but one of the aforementioned files. Launching the program from Visual Studio 2017 environment everything works correctly. If I make the installation disk and install it, I no longer see the strings. How can I solve the problem?

I created two .resx files: Resources.en.resx and Resources.it.resx (under Properties) and a menu to choose the language.

I create class to manage the language:

```
public class LanguageConfiguration: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public CultureInfo MyCulture { get; set; }

    private string _langName= "en";
    public string LangName
    {
        get => _langName;
        private set
        {
            if (value == _langName) return;
            _langName= value;
            UpdateLanguage();
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }        


    private LanguageConfiguration ()
    {
        UpdateLanguage();
    }

    public void UpdateLanguage()
    {
        Cultura = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(_langName);

    }

 }
```

In the ViewModel of the Main Form:

```
public class ViewModelMain : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public readonly LanguageConfiguration Language;
    public ResourceManager Translation{ get; set; }

    public ViewModelMain(Action<Action> invoker)
    {
        Language = new LanguageConfiguration();
        var Translation=  new GestoreTraduttore(TraduzioneHelper.Namespace, TraduzioneHelper.Assembly);
        Translation = new ResourceManager($@"{typeof(ViewModelMain).Namespace}.Properties.Resources", typeof(ViewModelMain).Assembly);
    }
```

I expect a label on the Main form to change as the selected language changes (LangName). And in fact this happens, launching the program from the "Play" button.

At this point I create an installation disk using the Visual Studio 2017 Setup Project, install and launch the application: the label remains white.

I have verified that also in the installed application the language is selected correctly, but in any case the strings are not displayed.